# fetching data type Decimals from Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, decimal

i have field "price" with type Decimals in my mysql database table,
the value is 200000.00

but if i fetch in to my website using PHP, it always showing 0.00
i already double check and make sure my query and fetch script correct

is there a specific way to fetch decimal to php ?

This is my code

```
$query_price = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tblpricing` WHERE `relid`='2' AND `currency`='1'");
  $fetch_price = mysql_fetch_array($query_price);
  $priceun = "$fetch_price[annually]";
```

thank you

Comment: There is nothing special about decimals in PHP. Actually, if there are only zeros after the decimal, you will probably find that it will automatically get truncated to 200000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
print(number_format($price, 2));
```

Comment: I think the question was saying that there is only a zero value coming through the code, rather than an incorrectly formatted one? Could be wrong though.

Comment: it still not working, i just update the script that i use in my question

Comment: $priceun = $fetch_price['annually']; or $priceun = $fetch_price[0];